# Showing text in intervals using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to show a text in intervals using FFmpeg, for example showing "Hello" for 10 seconds, hide it for 30 seconds and repeat the operation over and over....

Is there a way to do that?

I'm able to show the text in some interval but don't know how to repeat it...

Thanks.

LordFord.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the drawtext filter.

Add the enable option like this:

```
enable='lt(mod(t,40),10)'
```

With the above expression, for each 40 seconds, the text is shown for the first 10 seconds and hidden for the rest. `mod` is the modulus function. `lt` is the less-than function.

Basically, if enable evaluates to non-zero, the filter is active.